# Quarterly date picker

Tags: javascript, angular

I am looking for a quarterly date picker, preferably using Angular, like something shown below:

[image]

Both Bootstrap and (Angular) Material dont seem to offer this functionality.

Is there any other existing frameworks/libraries that could offer this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use, e.g. an autocomplete in material, some like

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="change(-1)"><</button>{{year}}<button mat-icon-button (click)="change(1)">></button>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options;let i=index" [value]="option.value">
        {{option.value}}<span *ngFor="let month of option.months">{{month}}</span>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

options: any[] = [
    {value:1,months:['Ene','Feb','Mar']},
    {value:2,months:['Apr','May','Jun']},
    {value:3,months:['Jul','Ago','Sep']},
    {value:4,months:['Oct','Nov','Dec']}
  ];
  year=new Date().getFullYear()
  change(inc)
  {
    this.year+=inc
  }
```

see a fool example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kanv4q?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.ts)